# git difftool --dir-diff is not creating temp files for Beyond Compare 3 to use

Tags: git, msysgit, beyondcompare3

I'm trying to use git's new (as of git 1.7.11) directory diff command with Beyond Compare 3 as the difftool, but the temporary files are not being created.

For example:

`git difftool --dir-diff <branch1> <branch2>`

Beyond Compare opens a directory comparison with the correct directories and changed files listed.

However, when I click on any of the files I get the following error:

`Unable to load C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\git-difftool.yG8V5\left\<path to some file>: The system cannot find the path specified`

So, I check to see if the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\git-difftool.yG8V5` directory exists and it doesn't.

Beyond Compare 3 works fine as the difftool for non-directory diffs and merges.

I'm using git for Windows (msysgit) 1.8.0.

Here are the relevant .gitconfig settings:

```
# External Visual Diff/Merge Tool
[diff]
    tool = bc3

[difftool "bc3"]
    path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe"

[merge]
    tool = bc3

[mergetool "bc3"]
    keepTemporaries = false
    trustExitCode = true
    keepBackup = false
    path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BComp.exe"
```

Comment: It appears that the issue is that Beyond Compare isn't holding the console session (BComp.exe) open when launched with the --dir-diff flag, so Git is deleting the temp directory before BC can read it. According to the [BeyondCompare commandline reference](http://www.scootersoftware.com/help/index.html?command_line_reference.html), BComp.exe has special behavior when launched from a version control system. I suspect whatever it's using for inference is broken with this flag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a solution described [here](http://theo.im/blog/2012/10/27/directory-comparison-for-git-difftool/).  Basically, if you modify your .gitconfig to use `BCompare.exe` instead of `BComp.exe`, the console session will remain open until the Beyond Compare window is closed.

Modify your .gitconfig settings to read:

```
# External Visual Diff/Merge Tool
[diff]
    tool = bc3

[difftool "bc3"]
    path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/BCompare.exe"
```

Comment: This works for me. However, instruction on beyond compare website is wrong

Comment: This did not work for me ("unknown tool"). So, instead of `path = ...` I got it working with `cmd = C:/path/to/bcompare.exe \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"`

Answer (score 6):

Answer from Scott Wegner is have small drawback - if you try to run 2 compares simultaneously, second will not work. This is because BCompare.exe do not run second application instance and so, close started process too early.

Sadly, BCompare.exe does not understand `/solo` command line option, so I write small bat file in Beyond Compare 3 installation directory:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompD.bat

```
start /wait "" "%~dp0/bcomp.exe" %* /solo
```

and use it as tool

```
[difftool "bc3dir"]
    path = C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcompd.bat
    cmd = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Beyond Compare 3/bcompd.bat\" \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

I do not use this as default diff tol, so I name it `bc3dir` and use like next:

```
git difftool --dir-diff --tool=bc3dir 760be6d47d35b42a6a2409636b40a5521361e72f^ 760be6d47d35b42a6a2409636b40a5521361e72f
```

Comment: Nice wrapper for BC. +1

Comment: the `bcompare.exe /solo` option works fine with the BC 3.1.9, so did not have to use a batch file. To integrate this with `git difftool`, I had to use it as `-solo`, since the `sh.exe` would otherwise interpret that as a path

Answer (score 6):

I tried [@ScottWegner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13637243/5671993)'s answer, but it only works when Beyond Compare is not already running. I found the solution with the help of [@SergeyAzarkevich](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42480677/5671993) 's answer. This is what I did in my `.gitconfig`

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "bc3"]
    cmd = \"c:/program files (x86)/beyond compare 3/bcompare.exe\" -solo \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
```

Notice the `-solo`. This causes Beyond Compare to spawn a new instance of the program.

On windows, we should be using the `/solo` option, but since `git difftool` command, spawns `sh.exe` to process its command-line, the `/solo` option was getting incorrectly interpreted as a path. So I have to use it as `-solo`

With this option, I run `start git difftool --dir-diff`, so this will free up my command prompt, and a new prompt will continue waiting for the new instance of Beyond Compare to exit. This will also make sure that the temp files/folders created by `git` will continue to live till the diff tool exits.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you have another case where `git difftool --dir-diff` might misbehave.

"`git difftool --dir-diff`" had a minor regression when started from
a subdirectory, which has been fixed with Git 2.12 (Q1 2017).

See [commit 853e10c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/853e10c19755669bd4695b1d9fd81f3278466727) (07 Dec 2016) by [David Aguilar (`davvid`)](https://github.com/davvid).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit afe0e2a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/afe0e2a391665c01daae78d8f8a9a105420b0218), 19 Dec 2016)</sup>

> ### `difftool`: fix `dir-diff` index creation when in a subdirectory
>
> [9ec26e7 (`difftool`: fix argument handling in subdirs, 2016-07-18, Git 2.9.3)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ec26e797781239b36ebccb87c590e5778358007) corrected how path arguments are handled in a subdirectory, but
>   it introduced a regression in how entries outside of the subdirectory are handled by `dir-diff`.
>
> When preparing the right-side of the diff we only include the changed paths in the temporary area.
>   The left side of the diff is constructed from a temporary index that is built from the same set of changed files, but it was being constructed from within the subdirectory.
>   This is a problem because the indexed paths are toplevel-relative, and
>   thus they were not getting added to the index.
>
> Teach `difftool` to `chdir` to the toplevel of the repository before
>   preparing its temporary indexes.
>   This ensures that all of the toplevel-relative paths are valid.